# How to make an histogram on gnuplot and how to format the data - c++

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I would like to know how to make an histogram with gnuplot. I have a file with all the position of some particles and I want to display where they accumulate. So I want to fill the bin of the position occupied by the particles. If the particles spend more time in a position I will have the frequency of that bin higher right. How I have to format my text.dat and which command I have to use to plot the isotgram? So essentialy I need to fill the x-bin each time that gnuplot reads the x-value (x-position).

Answer (score 0):

i have found . you just need to use the line command ' with boxes ' after plot "dati.dat" , so it becomes,

```
 plot "dati.dat" with boxes
```

you just need to write a file.dat with each single value in a row of the txt file.